# Calling a special jQuery function on click

Tags: jquery, function, click, tinyscrollbar

I'm using [tinyscrollbar](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/) and [script](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/js/jquery.tinyscrollbar.js). I want to have a button on my page which should simulate a mousewheel on clicking. I think it is the function `wheel(event)` in the tinyscrollbar-script which should be called. How can I do that?

```
$("#clickit").click(wheel);
```

But this does not work

Answer (score 1):

Try

$(document).ready(function(){

```
 $("#clickit").click(function(){
   $('#your_tinyscrollbar_id').wheel();     //Your function call
});
```

});

**[Updated]**

You can't : this function is actually private, and only accessible within the update function.

Here is the description of a initialized `tinyscrollbar` :

```
$('#your_scrollbar').data('tsb')             //Object description
    Scrollbar {update: function}
        update: function ( sScroll )
            arguments: null
            caller: null
            length: 1
            name: ""
            prototype: Object
            __proto__: function Empty() {}
            <function scope>                  //Private functions, accessible 
              Closure                         //only within the scope of the 
                drag: function drag( event )  //update function
                end: function end()
                iMouse: Object
                iPosition: Object
                iScroll: 0
                oContent: Object
                oScrollbar: Object
                oSelf: Scrollbar
                oThumb: Object
                oTrack: Object
                oViewport: Object
                oWrapper: p.fn.p.init[1]
                options: Object
                sAxis: false
                sDirection: "top"
                sSize: "Height"
                setEvents: function setEvents()
                setSize: function setSize()
                start: function start( event )
                touchEvents: false
                wheel: function wheel( event )
              Closure
            Global: Window
            __proto__: Scrollbar
```

Comment: @matin Try to be more explicit please : what doesn't work? Do the `click` event triggers? Is the `wheel()` function called? Check that with your javascript debugger

Comment: click does work. if i use $("#clickit").click(function(){
    alert('d');
 }); the alert is shown. but if i use $("#clickit").click(function(){
    wheel();
    alert('d');
 }); no alert is shown and function wheel seems not to be called because i also put an alert to this function. alert in function wheel is shown if is scroll the mousewheel

Comment: @matin Then it's your call to the `wheel()` function that doesn't work. Check that the `wheel()` function is in the scope

Comment: sorry, but i am not so good in this. the function wheel is a "subfunction" of function Scrollbar( root, options ) and this function is in ;( function( $ ) . so maybe i have to call another function first?

Comment: but i do not know how to check if it's in the scope :-(

Comment: ah ... sorry, did not see that there is a new code in answer first. i tried it, but does also not work

Comment: so this means i can not use the function outside? can i change the private function to public function?

Comment: @matin You can try, that might be hard, or impossible, I don't know. Anyway, this is beyond the scope of this question :), ask another one if you need further information. Feel free to valid or close this one